# Plugin for backend order create that sets attribute value on created order

Tags: magento2, orders, adminhtml, magento-2.1, plugin

I am attempting to set a custom attribute `require_verification` on a newly created order from the Magento backend using a plugin in Magento 2.

Many suggestions I have found recommend using events, which I was able to successfully implement. But I am specifically looking for information about how this can be done using a plugin. This is because the use of plugins is preferred over events in Magento 2.

I am attempting to run my plugin after the `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save` execute() method.

Save.php

```
namespace Training\RequireVerification\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create;

class Save
{ 
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save $controller, $result) 
    {

        $order = $controller->getOrder(); // DOES NOT WORK
        $order->setRequireVerification(0);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save">
        <plugin name="training-order-create-after-controller-plugin" type="Training\RequireVerification\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

The plugin is firing, so I know it is setup properly, I just need help understanding how to get access to the newly created order in the afterExecute method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the controller object does not contain the order and you are trying to call `getOrder()` on it. Magento dispatches an observer for this purpose, `sales_order_place_after`, and you can grab the order there. There are a variety of plugins that could be created for this purpose but the observer mentioned above is easiest.

If you only want this to occur for orders placed through the admin panel, you could implement a plugin for `Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create` with the method `afterCreateOrder($subject,$result)`. The `$result` variable will contain the actual order.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you aware of how you could get access to the newly created order from this plugin?

Comment: I just took a look at whats going on in the controller and nothing is immediately obvious that would allow this. Are you locked into using a plugin for this controller specifically? I can see that after order is placed, it redirects to `$resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);`. If you implement your plugin for that page, you could always grab the `order_id` param.

Comment: Not locked into using a plugin, I'm just curious why there is no good way to get the order from here. That is a good suggestion, but it seems that it only passes that param if there are permissions to Magento_Sales::actions_view (which is probably ok most of the time), but obviously not a robust solution considering I'm trying to set an important verification flag every time regardless of permissions.

Comment: Using a plugin against a controller is really not the best course of action at all to obtain data from a model. I suggest the observer because executes any time an order is placed, regardless of whether placed from frontend or admin, regardless of whether params or post data are available, etc. Its hooked into the functionality, not the page on which the order takes place.

Comment: Do you want this functionality every time an order is placed or ONLY when placed through admin?

Comment: I just added an alternative method to my answer above.

Comment: Yes, my objective is that an order attribute `require_verification` be marked with a 0 when submitted from the backend, and with a 1 when submitted from the checkout.  The reason for using the plugin was mostly just to learn more about plugins, because I'm confused when to use them vs events, but I assumed either would always be a possibility (even if not easier/favorable).

Comment: I think plugins are awesome. I am a full time Magento dev and I have to say that I don't know if one is better, but I am definitely enjoying the use of plugins. Plugins also add a little bit of overhead in the core code in terms of making them work. Although for accessing a single order, the amount of overhead would be minimal.

Comment: In regards to  your comment about the observer executes any time an order is placed, but this could still be used if the events.xml is placed under the etc/adminhtml/events.xml which would only supply these event observers within the **adminhtml** area, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was typing at 3am, totally forgot. Yes, you can implement observers either globally or per area.

Comment: Also, the plugin I mentioned in my answer will only be for admin-placed orders so you have two viable solutions.